Can a Call and a Put with same strike price and expiration date and underlying asset have different implied volatility?
Furthermore, assume that the current price of the underlying asset equals the strike price of the options.
If volatility measures variance without a direction, it doesn't make sense to me that the volatility would be different for a call than for a put with the otherwise same variables.
All this reasoning makes me conclude that the IV should be equal for the call and the put in this case.

European or American. For the latter, it's perfectly reasonable that IV isn't identical, also theoretically.

In theory, they shouldn't, but in the real world, it is possible.
In Theory: Call and put options of the same strike and expiry should obey put call parity and thus have the same IV.
In Practice: Call and put prices should obey put call parity due to potential arbitrage opportunities but sometimes there are arbitrage costs such as bid-ask spreads that are unnecessarily wide that make the arbitrage unprofitable. Therefore, they can have (slightly) different IVs.
